# How can I get Visual Studio cmd parameters for debugging working?

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, console, .net-5

Currently I'm working on a WPF-App. It should be launched by command line with a single parameter.
I defined:

```
public App([Optional] string[] args)
{
    //string[] args = new string[] { "UK356715586" };
    Console.WriteLine("accessed app");
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {                
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before PONumber Setting");
        PONumber = args[0].ToString();
    }

    //PONumber = "UK356715586";
}
```

I set this debug setting for the given parameter:

[image: Debug setting in Visual Studio with a command line argument and working directory set.]

By launching in VS I'm getting:

> instance of an object."
>
> "args" war "null".

What can i do?

Comment: The easiest was is to override the [OnStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create a constructor with a parameter declared as `[Optional]`. It is never assigned. If you remove the attribute, you will even get a compilation error.

Instead use the built in `Startup` event of the `Application` type. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startup?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks):

> A typical Windows Presentation Foundation application may perform a variety of initialization tasks when it starts up, including:
>
> - Processing command-line parameters.
>
> [...] application-scope properties and command-line parameters can only be used programmatically. Programmatic initialization can be performed by handling the `Startup` event [...]

Assign an event handler in `App.xaml` and implement it in `App.xaml.cs`.

```
<Application x:Class="YourWpfApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             Startup="App_OnStartup">
   <Application.Resources>
      <!-- ...your resources. -->
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("accessed app");
      if (e.Args.Length == 0)
      {                
          Shutdown(-1);
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Before PONumber Setting");
          PONumber = e.Args[0];
      }
   }

   // ...other code.
}
```

An alternative is to override the `OnStartup` method in your `App` type. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks):

> `OnStartup` raises the `Startup` event.
>
> A type that derives from `Application` may override `OnStartup`. The overridden method must call `OnStartup` in the base class if the `Startup` event needs to be raised.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnStartup(e);

      Console.WriteLine("accessed app");
      if (e.Args.Length == 0)
      {                
          Shutdown(-1);
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Before PONumber Setting");
          PONumber = e.Args[0];
      }
   }

   // ...other code.
}
```